# docker compose on azure: volume definition is not accepted

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

when doing a docker compose up of a multi container app, I get an error about my volumes definition:
services.volumes Additional property nginx is not allowed.

in my docker-compose.yaml, I defined the volumes as prescribed by docker:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/aci-integration/#using-azure-file-share-as-volumes-in-aci-containers.

my docker-compose.yaml:

```html
version: '3.4'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nginxdata/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - nginx/basic_auth:/etc/nginx/basic_auth
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      
volumes:
  nginxdata:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: nginxdata
      storage_account_name: mystorageacct
  nginx:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: nginx
      storage_account_name: mystorageacct
```

When I do a docker compose up, I get the error:
"services.volumes Additional property nginxdata is not allowed".

Note: the azure shares exist and and for example, this works:

```html
docker --context myaci run --name=nginxvolip -p 80:80 -v mystorageacct/nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

Did I miss something? Help is welcome!

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the example that works fine:

```
docker --context myaci run --name=nginxvolip -p 80:80 -v mystorageacct/nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

This command means you mount the File Share `nginx` in the storage `mystorageacct` to the path `/usr/share/nginx/html` and there is no problem. But in the docker-compose file, you configure the mount like this:

```
volumes:
      - nginxdata/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - nginx/basic_auth:/etc/nginx/basic_auth
```

It seems you want to mount the folder inside the File Share to the path inside the container. And that's the problem. You cannot mount the folders inside the File Share to the container, only the File Shares you can mount. And the error also shows the keywords that **Additional property** is not allowed. So the available mount should like this:

```
volumes:
      - nginxdata:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - nginx:/etc/nginx/basic_auth
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. You're right, only the File Shares can be mounted.

The additional property error was related to wrong indentation in the yaml; the volumes definition should be on the same level as the services definition but it wasn't.
After fixing both issues it works.
Thank you Charles.